# SOAPUI database connection error[local port 127.0.0.1:4321 cannot be bound]

Tags: database, groovy, ssh, soapui

local port 127.0.0.1:4321 cannot be bound, please see code below for details, note that i am using the lport - 4321. Do i need to use something different? If yes, how can i find one?

```
package mypackage
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session


// ssh login
String sshHost = 'abc.com'
String sshUser = 'test'
String sshPass = 'test'
int sshPort = 22
String boundaddress ="0.0.0.0";
// database login
targetHost = 'localhost'
targetUser = 'test'
targetPass = 'test'
targetPort = 3306
lport = 4321

JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, sshPort);
session.setPassword(sshPass);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
session.connect();
int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, targetHost, targetPort);

Connection con = null;
String driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionString = "jdbc:mariadb://" + targetHost +":" + lport + "/";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, targetUser, targetPass);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * company "
st.execute(sql);
```

Comment: Where are you running this from? If from a SoapUI script, you should not have a `package` statement.

Comment: Yes I am running it from SOAPUI. After removing the package statement. I get the same error.

Comment: I added the line - com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") but now is returning true only instead of returning the table. Possibly using the wrong lport?

Comment: Execute doesn't return a result set. You need executeQuery

Comment: It says org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.queryresults.resultset.MariaSelectResultSet@8f89d8. Also, I need to keep changing the lport otherwise it throws an error - com.jcraft.jsch.JSchExcepttion: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:59392 cannot be bound.